# Thymeleaf - Exception evaluating SpringEL expression

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using `#strings.substr()` function and it gives the following error:

> There was an unexpected error `(type=Internal Server Error, status=500)`.
>   Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: `"#strings.substr(status,iter.index,iter.index+1)"` (init:37)

This is the code:

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="task,iter : ${taskList}">
    <td th:text="${task.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${task.task}"></td>
    <td th:switch="${#strings.substr(status,iter.index,iter.index+1)}">
        <div th:case="'0'"><input type="checkbox"/></div>
        <div th:case="'1'"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/></div>
        <div th:case="*"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbtn" checked="checked"/></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the error log:

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#strings.substr(status,iter.index,iter.index+1)" (init:37)] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 9): Method call: Method        substr(netgloo.models.Exit,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer) cannot be found    on org.thymeleaf.expression.Strings type
```

I guess the error is due to the fact **iter.index** is of type **Integer** and the function expects an **int**. So how do I solve this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the problem is (quoting from your error message):

> Method substr [...] cannot be found    on org.thymeleaf.expression.Strings type

That means `#strings` doesn't have a method called `substr`. You probably mean `substring`.

See http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings